# Exception handling in static initializer

Tags: java, javafx

Normally I handle my exceptions by showing some custom Alert (JavaFX) with details, but JavaFX runtime is not initialized at all when the static initializer of my class runs.

Is there any way to handle such exception without printing its content to output like an animal?

```
public class MyStaticInitializedClass {

    static {
        try {
            //do the things that may throw exception
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ExceptionHandler.showException(ex);
        }
    }

}

public class ExceptionHandler {

    public static void showException(Exception ex) {
        //constructs JavaFX alert with exception details
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I like the "like an animal" part but i'm going to need to see some code first.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? What would you like to happen? Why not simply let the application crash?

Comment: @Slaw I'd like to know what happened

Comment: If a static initializer fails that normally means something is seriously wrong with the environment. If this is part of your application startup I would personally let the application crash and log the reason. But if you can recover from the class failing to load, and you really want to show an alert, then consider placing the exception in a queue and check the queue after the JavaFX runtime is initialized. In either case, it's a good idea to log the exception (as well).

Comment: @Slaw I've been thinking about that "queue" thing, but how can I do this? As we know, in the static initializer step other things (like fields) may not be properly initialized. I'll try to initialize some kind of 'exception container' first in the initializer and then do the rest of the code. Many thanks!

Comment: The "book answer" is to catch the exception and throw a [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) for the reasons @Slaw explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consder if you shouldn't let the application simply crash and log the reason. A failure in a static initializer typically means there's something seriously wrong with the environment, which is not likely something you can recover from. Also, as far as I know, once a class fails to load it can't ever be loaded by the same `ClassLoader` again.

That said, if you want to show errors to your user in an alert, even if the error occurs before the JavaFX runtime has been initialized, then you need to save the error somewhere. Then, once you launch JavaFX, check wherever you stored the error(s) and show them. For example:

Main.java:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // an "error" before JavaFX is launched
    App.notifyUserOfError(new RuntimeException("OOPS!"));
    Application.launch(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

App.java:

```java
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  private static Queue<Throwable> errorQueue;
  private static App appInstance;

  public static synchronized void notifyUserOfError(Throwable throwable) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(throwable);
    if (appInstance == null) {
      if (errorQueue == null) {
        errorQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
      }
      errorQueue.add(throwable);
    } else {
      if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        appInstance.showErrorAlert(throwable);
      } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> appInstance.showErrorAlert(throwable));
      }
    }
  }

  private static synchronized Queue<Throwable> setAppInstance(App instance) {
    if (appInstance != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    appInstance = instance;

    var queue = errorQueue;
    errorQueue = null; // no longer needed
    return queue;
  }

  private Stage primaryStage;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("Hello, World!")), 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    var errors = setAppInstance(this);
    if (errors != null) {
      // if non-null then should be non-empty
      do {
        showErrorAlert(errors.remove());
      } while (!errors.isEmpty());
      // possibly exit the application if you can't recover
    }
  }

  private void showErrorAlert(Throwable error) {
    var alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
    alert.setContentText(error.toString());

    var sw = new StringWriter();
    error.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));

    var area = new TextArea(sw.toString());
    area.setEditable(false);
    area.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 12));

    var details = new VBox(5, new Label("Stack trace:"), area);
    VBox.setVgrow(area, Priority.ALWAYS);
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(details);

    alert.showAndWait();
  }
}
```

The above puts the error in a queue if JavaFX has not been initialized yet. At the end of the `start` method the queue is checked for any errors and they're displayed to the user one after the other. If JavaFX has already been initialized then the error is immediately shown to the user.